# Was the Yeti Airlines Flight 691 crash the first time a commercial airline crash was livestreamed from a plane?

Tags: accident-investigation

The Yeti Airlines Flight 691 crash that happened on 2023-01-15 was livestreamed by a passenger in the plane. Was the Yeti Airlines Flight 691 crash the first time a commercial airline crash was livestreamed from a plane?

Comment: Not an answer but a note: while most major news reports are stating that the video in question is genuine (https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-64287331) the usually-aviation-authoritative AvHerald currently has taken the opposite view (https://avherald.com/h?article=503c63e9&opt=0).